# Facing Issue while configuring Service-hook for Jenkins build job : Jamal Hartnett pushed updates to Fabrikam-Fiber-Git:master

Tags: git, jenkins, azure-devops, webhooks, githooks

I am working on configuring the Jenkins Build-job from VSTS-Service Hooks.

I have completed below for configuring the Build-Job with Service Hooks.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

The Url which I configure in Jenkin Base URL is below

```
http://username:password@jcibts-build-jenkins.some.com:9080/job/jcibts-swm-dev-admin-portal-bd/build?token=sometoken
```

**If I hit the same URL from browser my Jenkins Build job get triggered. On the other hand if I configure this URL in Service Hook I am getting below exception**.

[image: Exception]

Kindly advice if I configure some steps wrong or Is there any way to overcome this exception ??

Answer (score 1):

Using this URL `http://jcibts-build-jenkins.some.com:9080` instead.

Regarding build definition in Jenkins, you need to check the **Build when a change is pushed to TFS/Team Services** option in **Build Triggers** section.

Comment: By `http://jcibts-build-jenkins.some.com:9080` I am able to connect to the Jenkins. But My main objective is to trigger the respective Jenkins Job after code check-in. How can I do that

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh Do you check Build when a change is pushed to TFS/Team Services option in Build Triggers section? if that is the case, then this job will be triggered if Jenkins receives a notification from TFS/Team Services for a Git repository defined in the Source Code Management section. If you want to trigger a specified job, choose Trigger generic build when configure Jenkins service hook.

Comment: On the other hand, choose TFS plugin for Jenkins in Integration level when configure Jenkins service hook.

Answer (score 0):

Within Jenkins, log in as the user that will be used in the Jenkins service connection or service hook. Click on teh down arrow to the right if the user name in the top right corner and select Configure.

**Under the API token section, create a new token and copy it to the clipboard.**

In Azure DevOps, use this **API token** rather than the user password when providing the credentials for the service hook or service connection.

I found this answer here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1049735/error-403-when-connecting-to-jenkins.html

Answer (score 0):

So just like @starian had suggested. Anyone with the same issue should use the url: `http://jcibts-build-jenkins.some.com:9080` but that's specific to the one in the Question. For you it should be like `http://yourjenkinsbaseurl:portnumber`

Then proceed to jenkins and at the extreme top right, click >> Configure
and then in the API Token section, write an API name and click generate.
Copy the API token Generated

[image: API DESC shown]

In the Service hook make sure you get all the fields correct. Make sure to set the perform this action as 'Triger Generic Build'
Shown in the link >>

[image]

The Copied token paste it to the Azure password field and Note Most importantly  worked for me after so many fails. I supplied the same in the Build API field.

This gave a successful run for my generic build.